# Matching a specific digit in regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have two string data. My requirement is - two strings should match if their corresponding digits are exactly same or either one or both of them are ?. So two strings will be different only when their corresponding digits are different.

```
String str1 = "??56??77??";
String str2 = "??????77??";
```

I do not want to go for while loop and do digit by digit comparision. Is there any way that I could implement it using Java Regex.

Rough idea is to make str1 as pattern like

```
str1 = [0-9][0-9][5?][6?][0-9][0-9][7?][7?][0-9][0-9]
```

but how could i replace 5 with 5?

Please help.

Comment: why don't you want to use loop ? it's easy with loop.

Comment: Can you please add some sample strings matching and not matching ?

Comment: e.g.,str1 = ??56??77?? and str2 = ??????77?? are matching but

Comment: but str1 = ??56??77?? and str2 = ??57??77?? are not matching

Comment: str1 = ??56??77?? and str2 = ??????77?? are matching but 
str1 = ??56??77?? and str2 = ??57??77?? are not matching

Comment: so ideally at corresponding position if both are digits then they must be same or else both/either must be ? for two strings to match

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rough idea is to make str1 as pattern like
>
> str1 = [0-9][0-9][5?][6?][0-9][0-9][7?][7?][0-9][0-9]
> but how could i replace 5 with 5?

Yes you could use the `|` like `(5|?)` instead of your `[5?]`

so your pattern would become:

`str1 = [0-9][0-9](5|?)(6|?)[0-9][0-9](7|?)(7|?)[0-9][0-9]`

I still don't get your ? or [0-9] in your exemples, with concrete case it would be easiest to help. as this one won't match your `str2 = "??????77??"`

If str2 is really this the correct regex would be `??(5|?)(6|?)??(7|?)(7|?)??`

I can't tell as I really don't understand what you have as input...

Edit for your need you can play with it [here](http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/125704):

```
  String str1 = "??56??77??";
    String pattern = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++){
      char b = str1.charAt(i);
      if (b == '?') {
        pattern += "[0-9]";
      } else {
        pattern += "["+b+"?]";
      }
    }
    System.out.print(pattern);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: could you please tell me how exactly i could use it.

Comment: str1 = str1.replace("?", "[0-9]") will replace all ? with [0-9]

Comment: how could i make pattern str1 = [0-9][0-9][5?][6?][0-9][0-9][7?][7?][0-9][0-9] where i want digit to be replaced with [digit?]

Comment: actually i want pattern as str1 = [0-9?][0-9?][5?][6?][0-9?][0-9?][7?][7?][0-9?][0-9?] to match against str2 = ??????77??

Comment: [0-9?] is easy to do ...just replace ? with [0-9?]...problem is with [5?] as inplace of 5 digit can be any from 0-9